# Trying to use generic in XAML

Tags: xaml, generics, xamarin

I am working on XAML file in a Xamarin app.
I am trying to create the following class in XAML:

```
OnPlatform<Array<Cell>>
```

so far I wrote this but I am not sure how I can declare a generic type in TypeArguments.

My current (not working) XAML attempt:

```
      <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Array{Cell}">
      </OnPlatform>
```

what would be the correct XAML syntax please?

Comment: Never mind.. I create a non generic list type to use in Xaml. Problem solved!
(couldn't find how to include ArrayList Xamarin form)

Comment: Please remove your question since it can't be helpful.